# Google Cloud Functions API "Activation steps failed for services [[cloudfunctions.googleapis.com]]"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to create the basic weather assistant on api.ai. As part of the documentation I'm directed to set up a Google Cloud account and enable the GC Functions API on the project I've created. However, each time I try to enable it, it fails with the following error: "Activation steps failed for services [[cloudfunctions.googleapis.com]]"

Any advice would be appreciated.